# what's wrong with my wpf animation code

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, repeat

I'd like to repeat my animation for several times, every time the property of a target would change with it triggered or animation completed.

But the animition works only for the first time.

To simplify this, I just let a rectangle move from 0 to 400 in a canvas for 10 times. The code is followed.

I have searched questions like 'wpf repeat animation', which suggested to use `seek()` method or `rect.BeginAnimation(property, null)`, but doesn't work for me.

```
private void init()
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    this.RegisterName("rect", rect);
    rect.Height = 100;
    rect.Width = 50;
    rect.Fill = Brushes.LightBlue;
    Canvas.SetTop(rect, 0);
    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 0);
    myCanvas.Children.Add(rect);

    TargetAnimation(0);
}

private void TargetAnimation(int i)
{
    DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
    da.From = 0;
    da.To = 400;
    da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    Storyboard.SetTargetName(da, "rect");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(da);
    storyboard.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;
    storyboard.Begin(this);

}

private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (i < 10)
        TargetAnimation(++i);
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing an argument `i` to your `TargetAnimation` method? you are not using it...

Comment: Why not use the `da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;`?

Comment: I'm sorry for not making it clear. `i` is a global argument. @Pikoh

Comment: I just simplified the problem. Actually I need to change properties of the target every time like moving distance or duration. @JeroenvanLangen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should register completed event first before calling begin statement
like this:

```
storyboard.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;
 storyboard.Begin(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand StoryBoard.Completed. You should apply the delegate on da.Completed.

```html
        private void TargetAnimation(int i)
        {
            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            da.From = 0;
            da.To = 400;
            da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            da.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(da, "rect");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Children.Add(da);
            storyboard.Begin(this);
            //storyboard.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed `i` as a parameter but you did not use it or its value to determine. 
So you have to limit `TargetAnimation(int i)` value using if statement that is equal to the target animation value which is `i`